# The Help Center implies that it's OK to answer duplicate questions if there aren't many duplicates; is this correct?

Tags: support, answers, duplicate-questions, help-center

The [Help Center article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write a good answer contains the following section:

> Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some
> frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...
>
> - ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem.
> - ...solicit [opinions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) rather than facts.
> - ...have [already been asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search) and answered many times before.
> - ...require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions.
> - ...are not about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network as [defined in the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

The various bullet points here parallel the close reasons; in other words, it seems to be saying that you should not answer a question that should be closed (presumably because it should be closed instead).

The bullet point corresponding to duplicates (#3) is worded interestingly. Instead of referring to questions that "have been asked and answered before", it refers to questions that "have been asked and answered *many times* before". The implication of this is that it is okay to answer a question that has been asked once or even a few times before, as long as it has not been asked *many times* before.

Is this implication intended? I.e. is the official guidance that it is okay to answer duplicates up to a certain point? If not, can the implication be removed (by getting rid of the words "many times")?

Comment: It's not; see the subsection *Should I answer it?* on [our FAQ on duplicates](/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). I'd edit this so it just asks for this page to be edited otherwise.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ says that several duplicates are desirable. Perhaps that is what the Help Center is  alluding to?

Comment: @Alex duplicate questions are not much of a problem, as they tend to use different wording to ask the same question. That makes for a better discoverable question in the end. Ideally all related duplicates point to a single target which has a high quality answer. Also for non-registered users an (unanswered) duplicate automagically forwards the visitor to the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Luuklag I've seen many duplicates pointing to a page with poor answers, though. When the question marked as a duplicate has a good answer... also, I think that all the answers could be relevant, it would depend on the user interests.