# A user answering duplicate questions and dupe-hammering them afterwards

Tags: discussion, answers, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

For a long time now a six-figure user has been consistently answering questions from a certain tag and dupe-hammering quite a few of them right afterwards. I didn't think much of it until recently:

I answered a question, and shortly afterwards the user provided an answer too. I later saw that the question got marked as a duplicate of another post by the user, but as I didn't see the question as a duplicate of the post linked by the user, I reopened the question.

After a failed attempt to close the post again by the user *(it got pushed into the close-vote review queue and was invalidated)*, they proceeded to comment on my answer. The conversation went like this:

> **User:** Why did you reopen the question. This is a duplicate. It is about {...}. "duplicate" is nothing bad. It is just an indication that there is more information on the subject.
>
> **Me:** Because this question is not about {...}, but rather {...}. Yes, "duplicate" is nothing bad, but in this case I believe there is a better way to link to the extra information, like a comment or in the existing answers.
>
> **User:** Sorry, but I strongly disagree. This question is about {...}, so it is duplicate. The additional information in the "duplicate" questions will be very useful to this new contributor. (I've the feeling that you've voted to reopen, because you have answered the question.)
>
> **Me:** *"I've the feeling that you've voted to reopen, because you have answered the question"* Hmm... now why would that be a motive? Having a question answered by a user closed blocks out any "competition" (if rep is what you're insinuating) for that user. On the contrary, if a user with the duplicate hammer feels that a question is a duplicate of another post, they should mark it as so rather than providing an answer, no?
>
> **User:** No. It's okay to answer a question and mark it as "duplicate". I do so a lot. The "duplicate" has the general answer. However, the answer to the new question has some additional information about the specific code in the question.

What I'm interested to know is whether their last comment is true. Is it okay for a gold tag badge holder to answer a duplicate question of the tag and dupe-hammer it right afterwards?

To me it seems smart, as there will be less complaints from question askers, and it doesn't create more work for the close-vote reviewers *(as the duplicate question is already closed as such)*.

---

**EDIT:** The [FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) linked helps, but unlike every other section of that post, the ***Should I answer it?*** section *(the one that is supposed to answer this question)* is the only section that has its answer beginning with *"Generally..."*, leaving quite some wriggle room. With that wriggle room, and with how that section *(and the entire post)* doesn't mention anything about dupe-hammers, I believe this question can be reopened to fill in the gap.

Comment: [Strictly no in Math StackExchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/876009)

Comment: From Meta Stack Overflow: [Answering a question, then closing it as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286072/6045800). I don't think it should be considered acceptable. Either the question is a duplicate and any answer can (should) be posted on the target, or it is not a duplicate and it deserves an answer...

Comment: See the "Should I answer it" section from the faq post on duplicates. It doesn't matter who is closing.

Comment: "The "duplicate" has the general answer. However, the answer to the new question has some additional information about the specific code in the question." *Then it's not a duplicate*.

Comment: A recent MSO question on questionable hammer use: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411068/4014959

Comment: See the section: "[Should I answer it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)" and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367870/the-help-center-implies-that-its-ok-to-answer-duplicate-questions-if-there-aren - "If the asker really needs more help understanding the target's answers and you can't do this adequately in a comment, then you can add an answer that explains those answers. Think carefully about doing ...".

Comment: Only 6 figures?

Comment: "With that wriggle room and ... doesn't mention anything about dupe-hammers" >It doesn't matter if the question is closed by a dupe-hammer, a moderator, or 5 other users. The section *as written* addresses 'you', the reader of that section, regardless of whether you have a dupe hammer, moderator powers or just 'regular' close voting privileges. As for the 'generally', the section goes on to list exceptions, so it's as specific as it can get, there is no 'wiggle room' as you describe it. If it's not in the exceptions listed there, it falls under 'generally'.

Comment: If you need a more specific verdict on a more specific question, you're going to have to take that up on the meta of the site the question was on. You can link to the specific question in question there, and people can probably help you figure out if it really is a duplicate, if the content of the answer written by the gold-tag-badge-holder falls under the exceptions listed in the FAQ here or not. Without knowing the question, the FAQ is your answer; and if you want to discuss the specific question you need to go to child meta.

Comment: So their argument is that it’s ok for them to answer the duplicate but not for anyone else to answer it? If they are answering the duplicate with a different answer then it’s not a duplicate.

Comment: On sf story-id questions must have accepted answers before they can be closed as duplicates, so this is absolutely OK there.  Just with the additional wrinkle that the answer must be accepted.